# В отпуске или отпусках?

Tags: грамотная-речь, единственное-множественное-число

Дни, когда он находился в ежегодном или учебном отпусках (отпуске).

Answer (score 3):

**Дни, когда он находился в ежегодном (отпуске) или учебном отпуске.**

Выбору ед. числа  способствует **разделительный союз ИЛИ:**

Розенталь: [http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm#з_04](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm#%D0%B7_04)

Имя существительное, которому предшествует два или несколько определений, указывающих на разновидности предметов, ставится **в форме ед. числа**:

3)      если между определениями стоят противительные, **разделительные** или сопоставительные союзы, например: не норвежский, а голландский конькобежец; латинский или готический шрифт; то широкая, то узкая дорога;

Answer (score 2):

Всякий раз человек мог находиться только в *одном* отпуск**е**, к которому относились дни, о которых говорится: в том (ежегодном) **или** в другом (учебном).

Answer (score 1):

**Дни, когда он находился в ежегодном или учебном отпуске.**

Каждый раз он находился **в отпуске**, всегда в одном, а не в двух.

Answer (score 0):

Союз ***или*** указывает на неосведомлённость автора фразы в первом случае (*отпусках*): ежегодный и учебный *отпуска* случаются, но нет уверенности в каком году именно, а во втором — на безразличие автора к виду отпуска.

Оба варианта возможны при знании контекста. Во втором случае будет уместен вариант со скобками: «Дни, когда он находился в ежегодном (или учебном) отпуске».